# Proper Error handling EXPECT / TCL

Tags: tcl, expect

What is the best way to prevent sending commands to a dead process?

Sometimes my session gets terminated when it's supposed to be open so I end up sending commands and getting the error:

`send: spawn id exp4 not open`

I was trying to do something like

```
if [catch send "test\r"] {
      puts "send error!"
}
```

but it seems like the query is true every pass.

that's the simplest example, but I have more complex "send / expects" where I use capture groups etc, so putting a `catch` around every "send / expect" or creating a function doesn't seem that useful.

can you wrap a `catch` around the entire program? What is the proper way to catch errors like these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a FAQ written by the Expect author that addresses this: http://expect.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#q64

Seems like you want something like

```
expect_before {
    eof { respawning_the_process }
}
```

I'm sure there's some wrinkles to be ironed out (like what to do when the process is *supposed* to end)

The problem with this:

```
if [catch send "test\r"] {
```

is two-fold:

1. you did not put braces around the condition, so it's not getting evaluated at the right time.
2. you did not provide the right arguments to the `catch` command

You would want to write:

```
if {[catch {send "test\r"} output] != 0} {
```

This can be abstracted into a proc

```
proc send {args} {
    set status [catch [list exp_send {*}$args] output]
    # error handling if $status is non-zero
}
```

"exp_send" is a builtin alias for the expect "send" command, so it's safe to override "send" with a proc, minimizing the amount of code changes you need.